# File rename with same pattern

Tags: rename

I have a folder with a lot of picture of people. The pattern of the files are different it can be NAME_Firstname or NAME Firstname.

I want to set all the files with name_firstname. Is there another way of doing that than to modify them one by one?

Comment: That can be done with a batch/powershell script. However, we are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us **what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems**. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Advanced Renamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/). I use it all the time. It lets you

- add strings at specific positions
- replace or remove certain strings
- append strings
- restrict changes to actual filename or extension
- work on files within a folder or across folders
- sequence different changes
- etc.

And it's free.

For the case you mention you'll need two methods: one changing the space into an underscore, and one changing to lowercase.